# SQL Query creating copy of old SQL entry with two values changed

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with around 50 to 60 cols (and counting), and I would like to know whether I can create a generic query for INSERT ... SELECT to copy one row, but with two cols changed.

More specifically, I want to fetch one global config from table `configs` and insert it into table `configs` with flag `global` set to `false` and new `id` auto-increment value.

Sth. like:

```
INSERT INTO configs
(SELECT TOP 1 * FROM configs WHERE global=1)
UPDATE global=0, id=?
```

(And of course the new autoincrement id should be returned to me, for I have to update the user's profile.)

Comment: If you don't want to write the fields, use Query Designer to write the query, starting with `*`. The Query designer will expand the field names. Its simpler, safer, faster. What you are asking, is to convert a simple INSERT query to an `INSERT` followed by an `UPDATE`, obviously inside a transaction.

Comment: You have two extra columns in second table or you just want to update the value ?

Comment: It's the same table, so I don't have two additional columns. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a fully functional solution with a demonstration of how it works. I'm assuming you are completing this action inside a stored procedure. I basically clone the current global=1 row into a temp table, then drop off the IDENTITY column so you can use SELECT * to reinsert the record. By using SELECT *, you will not have to update this whenever the column count increases.

```
-- setup demonstration with two sample columns of data
CREATE TABLE #configs (ID INT IDENTITY(100,1), [Global] INT, ColA CHAR(2), ColB VARCHAR(2));

-- fill with values
SET NOCOUNT ON;
INSERT #configs VALUES (1,'AA','BB');
INSERT #configs VALUES (1,'CC','DD');
INSERT #configs VALUES (1,'EF','GH');
SET NOCOUNT OFF;

-- This is the target ID we are working with
DECLARE @CloneID INT = 100;

-- Examine the ID
SELECT * FROM #configs WHERE ID=@CloneID;

-- This work should be completed in a transaction
BEGIN TRANSACTION;

-- copy current "global=1" record into a temp table and change its value to 0
SELECT * INTO #temp FROM #configs WHERE ID=@CloneID AND [Global]=1;
UPDATE #temp SET [Global]=0;

-- drop off the IDENTITY column so we can select it into main table again
ALTER TABLE #temp DROP COLUMN [ID];

-- copy the old "global=1" record back into main table, its value has been changed
INSERT #configs SELECT * FROM #temp;

COMMIT;

-- Examine
SELECT * FROM #configs;

-- cleanup 
DROP TABLE #temp;
DROP TABLE #configs;
```